# how to get place detail in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am working on application in which i want place id for specific name which i am passing in request and want to get all places ID

```
function callback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var data;

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                     data += "The data is " + results[i] + "<br>";

                }
                document.getElementById('place_name').innerHTML = data.name;

                //document.getElementById('place_id').innerHTML = data.place_id;
                //document.write(data);   
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            // var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            //document.getElementById('place_name').innerHTML = place.name;       
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                //   placeId: place.place_id,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                        'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                        place.formatted_address);
                // infowindow.setContent(place.address_components);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
```

I am able to print name and id in marker but i just want to get all place id.
any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: You can just create an array to hold all the place ids. You add the id to your array like this `placeIDs[i] = results[i].place_id` inside your `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link from google could help you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder?hl=es

Good look.